# remove control characters from string using TR

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, ubuntu, tr

Please try the following commands:

`echo "(After Sweet Memories) Play Born To Lose Again" | tr '(' '-' |  tr ')' '-' |  tr ' ' '-'`

`-After-Sweet-Memories--Play-Born-To-Lose-Again`
(notice the double `--`)

I'm unable to modify the command and pass a (null) value instead i have to pass another `-`

see this example and this error:

`echo "(After Sweet Memories) Play Born To Lose Again" | tr '(' '' |  tr ')' '' |  tr ' ' '-'`

`tr: tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-emptywhen not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty`

Answer (score 19):

You can use "tr -d" to just remove chars. Is this the solution you are searching for?

```
echo "(After Sweet Memories) Play Born To Lose Again" | tr -d '(' |  tr -d ')' |  tr ' ' '-'
```

After-Sweet-Memories-Play-Born-To-Lose-Again

Comment: You can also delete both parenthesis characters with a single run of `tr -d '()'`

Answer (score 1):

A `tr` solution has been provided, but `tr` requires you run multiple instances in a pipeline. You can do it all in one process with `sed`.

```
echo "(After Sweet Memories) Play Born To Lose Again" | sed 's/ /-/g; s/[()]//g;'
After-Sweet-Memories-Play-Born-To-Lose-Again
```

You can even lose the `echo` (though that's hardly an issue...)

```
sed 's/ /-/g; s/[()]//g;' <<< "(After Sweet Memories) Play Born To Lose Again"
After-Sweet-Memories-Play-Born-To-Lose-Again
```